# How to update product attributes in woocommerce using rest API

Tags: rest, api, woocommerce, attributes

I can't figure out how the rest API parameters (WC 2.6+) should be formatted to update the attributes for a simple product when one or more of the attributes are global attributes. IMO it's a sign of bad design when you can't use the output parameters from a read to update the product successfully.

Example:
I have a product with 2 attributes (one global and one product specific). When I read the product using the rest API the global attribute has an id, while the product specific has `id = 0`.

```
[{u'name': u'EAN', u'variation': False, u'id': 0, u'visible': False, u'position': 0, u'options': [u'543']}, 
{u'name': u'Artikkelnr', u'variation': False, **u'id': 8**, u'visible': True, u'position': 2, u'options': [u'203884']}]
```

If I use the attributes property from the product to update it, the global attribute turns into a product specific attribute since global attributes are not supposed to have the 'name' passed as a parameter.

```
[{u'name': u'EAN', u'variation': False, u'id': 0, u'visible': False, u'position': 0, u'options': [u'543']}, 
{u'name': u'Artikkelnr', u'variation': False, **u'id': 0**, u'visible': True, u'position': 2, u'options': [u'203884']}]
```

,
However I am unable to update global attributes at all using the REST API. Adding a product with global attributes works as expected. There should really be an option to manage single attributes for a product, not just all attributes every time there's a change.

Has anybody figured out if and how the attributes of a product can be updated correctly?

Comment: Hi Rajat! Did you figure it out?